# Getting a "checksum mismatch" error when trying to update my local using tortoise

Tags: tortoisesvn, checksum

The local copy is what I want to add, I dont care that its out of date. I know manually that this file is the latest and most up to date but I cant add it back to the server bc I dont have the most recent version checked out...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Save a copy of your file with a different name
2. Delete the original *local* copy
3. Get the latest version of the containing folder from Tortoise
4. Replace new local copy with the copy from step 1
5. SVN Commit to complete

If you have a problem with this, please paste the exact error message.

Comment: when i save slides1.ctp to the elements folder should i "add" it back using svn... even if i delete it fully im getting the same error

Comment: Reworded answer, basically you shouldn't be performing an 'add' to your svn.

Comment: still cant get past step 3... ive tried #1 two ways... saving slides.ctp as slides1.ctp in notepad++ also just renaming via tortoise...

Comment: sorry- hitting ENTER submits the comment... step #2 im not sure if im supposed to delete the local via tortoise or not, so im getting the same exact error when i try #3

Comment: ok i got a clean update i renamed as a totally new file then deleted existing OUTSIDE of tortoise

Comment: now i have slides10.ctp with no green checkbox and slides.ctp is gone... what to do:)

Comment: I'm assuming slides10.ctp is your copy?  If so, do an SVN Update on the folder. As long as the file isn't deleted from the repository, it should restore the latest version of slide.ctp for you.  This is the file you will overwrite with slides10.ctp

Comment: ok sorry - last question i think we are making progress.. by overwrite (im usually not this slow) do you want me to rename slides10 to slides.. and inside tortoise or outside.. im just new to svn and tortoise- overwriting on a traditional desktop is just dragging the file etc but thats not really an option

Comment: Yep, I mean overwrite in the traditional Windows sense, not anything specific to Tortoise.  Once you overwrite it you *should* be able to SVN Commit it back to your repository.

And don't worry about the confusion.  I love Tortoise, but I've had my issues with it as well.

Comment: you on skype? find me aeb137 if you are- im closing the question bc im close to giving up - but if you think we can resolve it in real time ping me:) thanks

Comment: Skype Username is dj.quimby .  At work now, but I'll look for you tonight when I get a free minute.